# Using a classmethod to retrieve or load data on init

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, class-method

I have a time-consuming database lookup (downloads data from online) which I want to avoid doing constantly, so I would like to pickle the data if I don't already have it.

This data is being used by the class which has this classmethod.

Is this a 'proper' or expected use of a classmethod? I feel like I could fairly easily refactor it to be an instance method but it feels like it should be a classmethod due to what it's doing. Below is a mockup of the relevant parts of the class.

```py
import os
import pickle

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.records = self.get_records()

    @classmethod
    def get_records(cls):
        """
        If the records aren't already downloaded from the server, 
        get them and add to a pickle file. 
        Otherwise, just load the pickle file.
        """
        if not os.path.exists('records.pkl'):
            # Slow request
            records = get_from_server()

            with open('records.pkl', 'wb') as rec_file:
                pickle.dump(records, rec_file)
        else:
            with open('records.pkl', 'rb') as rec_file:
                records = pickle.load(rec_file)

        return records

    def use_records(self):
        for item in self.records:
            ...
```

Is there also an easy way to refactor this so that I can retrieve the data on request, even if the pickle file exists? Is that as simple as just adding another argument to the classmethod?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hi , can you share us a sample of  what type of data are you storing using pickle ?

Comment: `records` is a list where each item in the list is a class with lots of data inside.

Comment: class method is like any other method - you can use arguments ie `def get_records(cls, download=False)` and then use variable `download`  to download data even if pickle exists.

Comment: class method are more expected when you use them without creating instance `Example.get_records()`. Because you don't use `cls` in `get_recors` so it could be even `staticmethod`. But you use it in `__init__` so for me it seem more natural to use it as normal method.